# Redundancy character when submit and download: additional "?" in the end

Tags: javascript, html, csv, forms

I have a piece of html code:

```
<form action="data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,Date%2CCommon%20Cold%20(United%20States)%2C%0A04/01/2013%2C24126%2C%0A05/01/2013%2C452516%2C%0A06/01/2013%2C424369%2C%0A07/01/2013%2C265199%2C%0A08/01/2013%2C280783%2C" method="LINK">
<center><input id="downloadCsvAndCloseButton" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" type="submit" onclick="$('#save-csv-dialog').dialog('close');" 
        value="Save and Close" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
</input></center>
</form>
```

When submitted the form, a csv file will be downloaded with the data in action. However, there will be a question mark "?" in the last character position of the downloaded file.

But if I just put the action string in the browser address bar, the downloaded file would be perfectly without "?".

```
data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,Date%2CCommon%20Cold%20(United%20States)%2C%0A04/01/2013%2C24126%2C%0A05/01/2013%2C452516%2C%0A06/01/2013%2C424369%2C%0A07/01/2013%2C265199%2C%0A08/01/2013%2C280783%2C
```

Does anybody know the reason? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML code is invalid in many ways.  First, `<center>` is depreciated so it is best not to use that.  Second, `<input>` is self-closing, so `</input>` is incorrect.  Third, `method="link"` is not correct.  This would fallback to `method="get"`, which gives the `?` at the end of your link.  I think you want to send a `post` request with valid syntax:

```
<form action="data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,Date%2CCommon%20Cold%20(United%20States)%2C%0A04/01/2013%2C24126%2C%0A05/01/2013%2C452516%2C%0A06/01/2013%2C424369%2C%0A07/01/2013%2C265199%2C%0A08/01/2013%2C280783%2C" method="post">
    <center>
        <input id="downloadCsvAndCloseButton" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" type="submit" onclick="$('#save-csv-dialog').dialog('close');" value="Save and Close" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
    </center>
</form>
```

I left the `<center>`, but I suggest you remove it.